# Storing userid with userid++ works, but the last user from three "default users" in the CSV file is getting useridd++

Tags: c#, list, linq, csv, methods

The title describes my problem: *Storing userid with userid++ works, but the last user from three "default users" in the CSV file is getting useridd++ and gets pushed down in the List and CSV file...*

So I have a small Console Application that reads a CSV file with three default users and stores three default users in a List. These three users need to stay on there index position at all times:

```
userid,username,email,password,userrole
1,Inkoop,inkoop@gimpies.nl,123,purchase
2,Verkoop,verkoop@gimpies.nl,123,sales
3,Beheer,beheer@gimpies.nl,123,admin
```

The read method that reads the CSV file and stores them in a List:

```
public static List<User> LoadUsersFromCSV()
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader("users.csv"))
            using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                // csvReader.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
                // csvReader.Configuration.IgnoreBlankLines = true;
                csvReader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
                // csvReader.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = (string header, int index) => header.ToLower();
                // csvReader.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
                csvReader.Read();
                csvReader.ReadHeader();
                    
                // Store all content inside a new List as objetcs
                var users = csvReader.GetRecords<User>().ToList();  
                    
                return users;
                
                // try
                // {
                //                   
                // }
                // catch (CsvHelper.HeaderValidationException exception)
                // {
                //     Console.WriteLine(exception);
                // }
                
            }
            
        }
```

The method that gets user input and stores the input in a List and writes the information to users.csv:

```
public void Register(List<User> users)
        {
            
            User usr = users.OrderByDescending(u => u.userid).FirstOrDefault();
            
            int userid = (usr == null ? 1 : usr.userid++);
            
            // Get user input
            Console.WriteLine("Enter username:");
            string username = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter email:");
            string email = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter password:");
            string password = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter userrole (typ admin, purchase or sales):");
            string userrole = Console.ReadLine();

            // Create fresh instance to save input in memory
            User user = new User(userid, username, email, password, userrole);
            
            // users.Skip(3); 
            // Adds the user to the excisting list           
            users.Add(user);

            FileOperations fo = new FileOperations();
            // Calling the method from FileOperations.cs to write the List here to a CSV file
            fo.WriteUsersToCSV(users);
            
        }
```

The write to CSV file method:

```
public void WriteUsersToCSV(List<User> users)
        {
            
            // overwrite the file each time; indicated by the `false` parameter
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter("users.csv", false))
            using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                // Order the list again so the userid's are asc
                users = users.OrderBy(u => u.userid).ToList();
                
                // csvWriter.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false; // commented out as we write the whole file every time including the header
                csvWriter.WriteRecords(users);
                Console.WriteLine("New user added to users.csv");
            }
        }
```

But then my problem: *Storing userid with userid++ works, but the last user from three "default users" in the CSV file is getting useridd++ and gets pushed down in the List and CSV file...*

Output CSV file when I add two new users:

```
userid,username,email,password,userrole
1,Inkoop,inkoop@gimpies.nl,123,purchase
2,Verkoop,verkoop@gimpies.nl,123,sales
3,Bas,bas@bas.nl,123,admin
4,Tim,tim@tim.nl,123,sales
5,Beheer,beheer@gimpies.nl,123,admin
```

I don't want the user Beheer to move down! I want the new user to be as last index of List and get the userid++.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The `++` operator, when placed *after* a variable, returns the variables starting value and then increments it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incrementing last userId instead of returning an id which is one higher than last one.

```
int userid = (usr == null ? 1 : usr.userid + 1);
```

Comment: Omg... That simple! The most simple things we miss sometimes... :-) Thank you!

Comment: This will also work the other way around I guess? So deleting users will -1 the chosen variable. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yes, if you delete a user which has the highest id, the next one you add will get this id instead, but if you delete a user which is in the middle you will have a gap in ids. If you want to make sure that doesn't happen, you can generate ids at the point of saving, but you still will have a problem when you remove user which was in a file already, as all ids will change.